# What's the tile format used by leaflet?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, geocoding, geospatial, leaflet

I'm planning a website which will use huge schematics, that is, raster images that are not photos. If they were photos and I were interested on displaying them as so, I would use  either [zoomify](http://www.zoomify.com/html5.htm), [IIPImage](http://iipimage.sourceforge.net/demo/) or [PanoJS](http://www.dimin.net/software/panojs/). Although all of these solutions offer HTML5 support, they are not entirely satisfactory for my purposes, as they are optimized for JPEGs, use arcane JavaScript or have non-smooth transitions.

So, I was thinking that perhaps I could use [leaflet](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/index.html) with custom tiles. That is, instead of connecting the javascript to a map server, I could connect it to my own tile-provider with the schematics. My rationale is that leaflet provides smooth rendering, the used tile pieces seem to be png, and that I could even use markers and vector layers.  But I came to a stumbling block:

What kind of tiles leaflet expects? Where is information about that? Would the map projection, or other geo-specific aspects that I'm not aware of, be a problem?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames